# What is the pattern `... | sudo tee /path/to/some/file > /dev/null` useful for?

Tags: shell

Is there a particular reason the subject pattern is better than simply using `... > /path/to/some/file`<del>, or `... | sudo cat /path/to/some/file` if the sudo is important</del>?

Comment: For instance, if you don't have access right for the directory  /path/to/some, but sudo has ....

Comment: Your second example (`... | sudo cat  /path/to/some/file`) doesn't make any sense. We use `tee` because it allows us to write a file with the elevated privileges from `sudo`, whereas just using `>` uses the privileges of your local shell. As a regular user compare the behavior of `echo hello | sudo cat > /etc/testfile` vs `echo hello | sudo tee /etc/testfile`.

Comment: @larsks You are right, `sudo cat` doesn't work. I somehow thought there must be a more direct way to write to a file the current user doesn't have write privilege to, but apparently `tee` is the conventional way. (One *could* use `... | sudo su -c 'cat > /root/test'`, but it's roundabout as well with the additional disadvantage of part of the command being a string which IDEs won't color for you..)

Comment: `sudo su` is malpractice in general -- there's nothing at all that `su` can do that `sudo` can't; _every_ use of `sudo su` could be replaced with `sudo -i` or `sudo -l` or otherwise a more targeted sudo invocation, with the benefits that `/etc/sudoers` can better control precise permissions for those targeted uses if one wants to build a fine-grained list of which users are able to run which escalated commands.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's not about whether sudo can do everything su can but rather that in `tee /some/path > /dev/null` the latter part is superfluous and `su` gets rid of the `>/dev/null`. Sadly, there isn't a command which writes its stdin to a file without also piping it to stdout.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan, the **only** point I'm making in the [comment at hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962533/what-is-the-pattern-sudo-tee-path-to-some-file-dev-null-useful-for?noredirect=1#comment137444886_77962533) is that you can use `sudo bash -c 'cat >/root/test'` more efficiently than `sudo su -c 'cat >/root/test'` (mind, `tee` is certainly better than either, but that's not something I was addressing at the time). If your response to it was somehow meant to counter that point, I'm perhaps missing how/why.